# Why does the Injection of autowired dependencies failed in Spring web-service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I started to work in a simple Spring web-service and getting the following errors provided below,

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>       Error creating bean with name 'blogEntryController': 
>       Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception 
>       is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>       Could not autowire field: private core.services.BlogEntryService
>       rest.mvc.BlogEntryController.service; nested exception is 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>       No qualifying bean of type [core.services.BlogEntryService] found for
>       dependency: expected at least 1 bean which 
>       qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency 
>       annotations:
>       {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The project structure is as following,

[Spring MVC project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTddz.png)

I have the following service code,

```
package core.services;

import core.entities.BlogEntry;

public interface BlogEntryService {

    public BlogEntry find(Long id); // Returns the BlogEntry or null if it can't be found
    public BlogEntry delete(Long id); // Deletes the found BlogEntry or returns null if it can't be found
    public BlogEntry update(Long id, BlogEntry data);
}
```

and, the following Controller code,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/blog-entries")
public class BlogEntryController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String test(){

        return  "view";
    }

    public BlogEntryController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    private BlogEntryService service;

    public BlogEntryController(BlogEntryService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{blogEntryId}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<BlogEntryResource> getBlogEntry(
            @PathVariable Long blogEntryId) {
        BlogEntry entry = service.find(blogEntryId);
        if(entry != null)
        {
            BlogEntryResource res = new BlogEntryResourceAsm().toResource(entry);
            return new ResponseEntity<BlogEntryResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<BlogEntryResource>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
 }
```

Update: Dispatcher Servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="rest.mvc"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I created the empty constructure as it was asked by the debugger earlier. I cant even see the `view.jsp` file returned from the test method. What should I  do now ?

Comment: Where is your `BlogEntryService` implementation class?

Comment: You should annotate your services with `@Service` annotation.

Comment: @elefasGR do I need to implement the class or the interface should just work fine ?

Comment: @Chaklader you should have the implementation class of the interface you are injecting in your project. Else how do you expect this to work?

Comment: @dty I just use the `@Service` annotation and still getting the same error.

Comment: You only have an interface. An interface, besides a contract, is nothing. Without an implementation of that interface, there will be no instance of that service and nothing will be done. This has nothing to do with Spring but is basic java knowledge (imho).

Comment: @Chaklader if your issue is solved accept the correct answer

Comment: The issue is  not solved till now.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
 private BlogEntryService service;
```

> Above lines says you are having class `BlogEntryService` annotated
>   with `@Service` or mentioned in bean tag or as component scan(package) in dispatcher-servlet xml.

If you are missing mentioning in any of one place you will get the exception `No qualifying bean of type [core.services.BlogEntryService] found for dependency:`

So your BlogEntryService interface should be

```
@Service
public interface BlogEntryService {
```

**Update :** In dispathcer-servlet.xml you have to mention the packages to scan for beans.In your case it is `rest.mvc`.Since it's an Interface you ***should have the implemented class***(annotated with `@Service`),which will have definition of interface methods.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Your Service layer Package" />
```

Comment: I just use the `@Service` annotation and this is still not working.

Comment: SHow your dispatcher servlet.xml

Comment: I provided the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file with the question and it includes `component-scan`

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my first comment beneath your question, you are missing the implementation class of the interface. An implementation class could be the one below, however you have to provide the functionality of the methods:

```
@Service
public class BlogEntryServiceImpl implements BlogEntryService {
    public BlogEntry find(Long id) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
    public BlogEntry delete(Long id) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
    public BlogEntry update(Long id, BlogEntry data) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that BlogEntryService bean class is not provided. Do you have some implementation class annotated wit @Service?

Comment: I have no other implementation class annotated with @Service. How could I provide `BlogEntryService` bean class ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you provide an implementation class for your interface and annotate it with @service, OR make the BlogEntryService interface extend CrudRepository and Spring will provide you with the proper implementation for your cruds :save, getAll, find...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an implementation of your service is missing.
Just annotating an interface with @Service is not enough for Spring to generate a bean unless you are extending your interface with some of the specific Spring Data interface (CrudRepository, Repository ...). In that specific case and if you respect sone convention Spring will be able to automatically generate the implementation for you.
Please have a look to the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories